# $.makeArray not working as expected?

Tags: jquery, arrays

I would like to get a final result like this:

```
emails: Array[4]
    0: "Athos"
    1: "Aramis"
    2: "Porthos"
    3: "D'Artagnan"
length: 4
```

but, when i use `$.makeArray` like this:

```
$.makeArray( names );
```

This is what I get:

```
emails: Array[1]
    0: "Athos, Aramis, Porthos, D'Artagnan"
length: 1
```

The var `names` comes from a textarea value: `$("textarea").val()`

Should I be using `push` or something else instead? or Am I doing something wrong with `$.makeArray`?

Comment: You could just split it right? `names.split(",")` ? Also [makeArray](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.makearray/) is not meant to convert a string to an array...

Comment: warning `$.` is deprecated in newer versions of jQuery

Comment: what are the values you are passing into `$.makearray`?

Comment: makeArray converts an array-like object to an array. It does nothing with strings.

Comment: @PSL - right! i could easily split the names, thx! - I tho makeArray will convert string to an array, oh well... thx again!

Comment: @user3135719 well, it did convert it to an array... just not the array you were looking for.

Answer (score 2):

`$.makeArray` will

> [Convert an array-like object into a true JavaScript array](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.makearray/).

It appears that you are passing a string, `"Athos, Aramis, Porthos, D'Artagnan"` to `makeArray`. A string is *not* array-like so jQuery will not be able to do anything with it and therefore, it just creates an array with your single string inside. `makeArray` is not the right function.

Instead, use [String.split](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) to break up the string into an array.

```
var str = "Athos, Aramis, Porthos, D'Artagnan";
var values = str.split(",")

console.log(values) // ["Athos", " Aramis", " Porthos", " D'Artagnan"]
```

Notice that you'll still have leading whitespace in the strings in the array. You may be interested in trimming those out as well by updating the `split` to use a regular expression that matches on whitespaces as well.

```
var values = str.split(/\s*[,]\s*/g)
console.log(values) // ["Athos", "Aramis", "Porthos", "D'Artagnan"]
```

Comment: I think you could also avoid trim and use `.split(/[,]\s+/g)`

Comment: @PSL I like that much better. I'll update my answers. Good suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so `$.makeArray()` is not made for this. This actually converts jquery node array to normal array.

Like if you are selecting nodes `$("p")` then it comes as in jQuerified array, and you want convert this array to a normal array. then you can use `$.makeArray()`;

for your current problem, you shpuld do like:

```
$(function(){
    var val = $.trim($("textarea").val()).replace("/\s/gi", "").split(",");
    console.log(val);
});
```

here is the jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ashishanexpert/yQXzR/